# how to get git working on git proxy

Tags: git, proxy

I use Shadowsocks, and then I configure:

```
git config --global http.proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

This is valid for 'http' and 'https', but should I configure the protocol prefix for 'git'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, avoid using the `git://` transport protocol, which uses the port 9418.

If you have urls configured with git://, use a gobal config like

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
```

That way, you will always be using https.

Since `git.linphone.org` only proposes Git repos through the `git://` protocol, try instead using their GitHub mirror counterparts:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications.insteadOf git://git.linphone.org
```

Comment: i try '$ git clone https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android.git --recursive  '.. but failed to clone

Comment: What is the error message? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: The but the project requires the recursive to load submodule, and some of its sub modules seem to have only Git

Comment: The global config should apply to all git repos/submodules

Answer (score 0):

I tried using proxifier to solve the problem